# RでCSVファイルの読み込みをする際にファイル名に引数を使う方法

Tags: macos, bash, r

シェルスクリプトとRを使って、フォルダ配下のcsvファイルに対して統計処理をしたいと考えています。
Input.csvという固定の名前ではなく、$hoge.csvのような名前で読み込めるようにするには、
どうすればいいでしょうか。

StartR.sh

```
#Rを起動する



#!/bin/bash
r --vanilla --slave < csv.R
```

csv.R

```
#CSVファイルを読み込む
a <- read.csv("Input.csv")
#CSVファイルを書き出す
write.csv(result, file='Output.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 使う関数

`commandArgs(trailingOnly = T)`

これでコマンドライン引数を取得できます.

### 準備

test.R を以下の内容で作成します.

```
arguments<- commandArgs(trailingOnly = T)
print(arguments[1])
print(arguments[2])
print(arguments[3])
```

### 実行の仕方

`$ R --vanilla --slave --args foo bar baz < test.R`

### 実行結果

> [1] "foo"
>   [1] "bar"
>   [1] "baz"

---

これでいかがでしょうか？